# mysql crosstab wrong sum total

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a problem sum total in mysql crosstab.

my coding as the following:

```
 SELECT IFNULL(Prtype,''Total'') as Prtype,sum(t.data) AS Total,',
 SUM(IF(office ='A',`data`, NULL)) AS 'A',
 SUM(IF(office ='B',`data`, NULL)) AS 'B',
 SUM(IF(office ='C',`data`, NULL)) AS 'C',
 FROM((SELECT Prtype, office,`data` as data
 FROM TBLGETDATAALL_1 GROUP BY office,Prtype,data) t) GROUP BY Prtype
```

The problem is total not equal sum of all office.

```
Simple data:

Type    Total   A   B   C
P1          3   2   1   1
P2          6   2   2   1
P3          6   3   1   1


Simple data 2:

Total: 50,455

(1,333  1,352   1,216   2,127   1,520   2,700   1,174   1,250   2,458   1,374   2,877   970 2,458   2,930   1,365   2,655   1,184   3,001   2,421   2,689   2,220   1,590   2,678   2,212   1,329)=49083

why total=50,455 and sum each office=49083 ?

---------
table name
Prtype    office  data
 p1         A     2
 P2         B     3
 P3         C     1
 ...   ...     ....    ....
----------
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      select Prtype , A , B , C , sum( A +B +C) as total from (
      SELECT IFNULL(Prtype,'Total') as Prtype ,
      SUM(IF(office ='A',`data`, 0)) AS A,
      SUM(IF(office ='B',`data`, 0)) AS B,
      SUM(IF(office ='C',`data`, 0)) AS C
      FROM TBLGETDATAALL_1
      GROUP BY Prtype ) t
      GROUP BY Prtype
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58285/1)

Comment: Dear echo me, it unknow column A and B.SELECT IFNULL(Prtype,''Total'') as Prtype,sum(A + B + C ) AS Total ,
     SUM(IF(office ='A',`data`, NULL)) AS A,
     SUM(IF(office ='B',`data`, NULL)) AS B,
     SUM(IF(office ='C',`data`, NULL)) AS C

     FROM((SELECT Prtype, office,`data` as data
     FROM TBLGETDATAALL_1 GROUP BY office,Prtype,data)

Comment: i edited your question please complete the sample data as i shown. your columns and some data

Comment: Done, A,B AND C is office.

Answer (score 0):

Use `0` instead of null

```
 SELECT IFNULL(Prtype,''Total'') as Prtype,sum(t.data) AS Total,',
 SUM(IF(office ='A',`data`, 0)) AS 'A',
 SUM(IF(office ='B',`data`, 0)) AS 'B',
 SUM(IF(office ='C',`data`, 0)) AS 'C',
 FROM((SELECT Prtype, office,`data` as data
 FROM TBLGETDATAALL_1 GROUP BY office,Prtype,data) t) GROUP BY Prtype
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with structure and sample data of TBLGETDATAALL_1

Comment: Dear Akhil, i have tried change null to 0 already still not corrret.